# Whats is the best way to encrypt a big array with AES in PHP?

Tags: php, performance, aes, mcrypt

### State

I have a big array of data (~2000 strings with 2000 chars each) to encrypt using symetric encryption AES.

My code is currently the following :

**Encryption function**

```
function encryptAES($content, $key) {
    $iv = mcrypt_create_iv(256, MCRYPT_DEV_RANDOM);
    $iv_base64 = rtrim(base64_encode($iv), '=');
    $encrypted = base64_encode(mcrypt_encrypt(
         MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256, 
         $key, 
         $content . md5($content), 
         MCRYPT_MODE_CBC, 
         $iv
    );
    return  $iv_base64 . $encrypted;
}
```

**Array Encryption**

```
foreach ($fields as $field) {
   $field['encryptedValue'] = encryptAES($field['value'], $SymKey);
}
```

.

### Question

Only strings can be passed to $content. And this code might be slow if I just make a loop over the thousands strings.

Can you suggest a more performant way ?

Comment: maybe serialize array?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. [`serialize()`](https://www.php.net/serialize) your array. The result of serialization is a binary string, which is acceptable by `mcrypt_encrypt`.
2. Encrypt serialized array with one function call, and `base64` the result:

   ```
    $myArray = [ ... ];
    $content = serialize($myArray);

    $iv = mcrypt_create_iv(256, MCRYPT_DEV_RANDOM);
    $encrypted = base64_encode(mcrypt_encrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256, $key, $content, MCRYPT_MODE_CBC, $iv);
   ```
3. There is no need for base64 encription of data passed to `mcrypt_encrypt`.

Comment: I get your point but this is not what I expect as I want to store the encrypted values independently in a database... As a function return, I want an array with each encrypted data... I'm thinking that there is no better way...

Comment: Well... in such case, you'll have to iterate through your array and encrypt each value with algorithm like the one above.